# Implementing Adapter into c++ program

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement Adapter which would enable me to use class "TecajnaLista" with function Statistika::prosjek.
End result I am looking for is to call function Statistika::prosjek like this:

```
> map<string, tuple<double, int>> pr = Statistika::prosjek(adapter);
```

Insted of this:

```
> map<string, tuple<double, int>> pr = Statistika::prosjek(p);
```

Program without Adapter looks like this:

**Za_adaptaciju.h**

> ```
> #pragma once
>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <map>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
>
> namespace PostojeciProgram {
>   class ITecaj {
>   public:
>       virtual void ucitaj(fstream*) = 0;
>       virtual const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const = 0;
>   };
>
>   class Tecaj : public ITecaj {
>   public:
>       void ucitaj(fstream*);
>       const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const;
>
>   private:
>       vector<tuple<string, double>> vrijednosti;
>   };
>
>   class Statistika {
>   public:
>       static map<string, tuple<double, int>> prosjek(ITecaj&);
>   };
>
>   void ispisi(map<string, tuple<double, int>>& pr);
>   void ispisi_tecaj();
> }
> ```

**Za_adaptaciju.cpp**

> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
>
> #include "za_adaptaciju.h"
>
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
>
> namespace PostojeciProgram {
>   void Tecaj::ucitaj(fstream* datoteka) {
>       string red;
>       while (true) {
>           *datoteka >> red;
>           if (datoteka->eof()) {
>               break;
>           } else {
>               int zarez = red.find(',');
>               string mjesec = red.substr(0, zarez);
>               double cijena = atof(red.substr(zarez + 1, red.size()).c_str());
>               vrijednosti.push_back({mjesec, cijena});
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   const vector<tuple<string, double>>* Tecaj::podaci() const {
>       return &vrijednosti;
>   }
>
>   map<string, tuple<double, int>> Statistika::prosjek(ITecaj& tecaj) {
>       map<string, tuple<double, int>> prosjek;
>       for (tuple<string, double> v : *(tecaj.podaci())) {
>           string kljuc = get<0>(v);
>           double nova_vrijednost = get<1>(v);
>
>           tuple<double, int>& p = prosjek[kljuc];
>           double vrijednost = get<0>(p);
>           int broj_pojavljivanja = get<1>(p);
>           if (broj_pojavljivanja == 0) {
>               prosjek[kljuc] = {nova_vrijednost, 1};
>           } else {
>               prosjek[kljuc] = {vrijednost + nova_vrijednost, broj_pojavljivanja + 1};
>           }
>       }
>
>       return prosjek;
>   }
>
>   void ispisi(map<string, tuple<double, int>>& pr) {
>       for (auto v : pr) {
>           string kljuc = get<0>(v);
>           tuple<double, int> v = pr[kljuc];
>           double n = get<0>(v) / get<1>(v);
>           cout << kljuc << ": " << n << endl;
>       }
>   }
>
>   void ispisi_tecaj() {
>       Tecaj p;
>
>       fstream f;
>       f.open("tecaj_eur.csv", fstream::in);
>       p.ucitaj(&f);
>
>       map<string, tuple<double, int>> pr = Statistika::prosjek(p);
>       ispisi(pr);
>   }
> }
> ```

**Main.cpp**

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include "za_adaptaciju.h"
>
> using namespace PostojeciProgram;
>
> void test_adapter() {
>   cout << "--- TECAJ - klasa Tecaj\n";
>   ispisi_tecaj();
>   cout << endl;
> }
>
> int main() {
>   test_adapter();
> }
> ```

My attempt:

**Za_adaptaciju.h**

> ```
> #pragma once
>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <map>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
>
> namespace PostojeciProgram {
>   class ITecaj {
>   public:
>       virtual void ucitaj(fstream*) = 0;
>       virtual const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const = 0;
>   };
>
>   class Tecaj : public ITecaj {
>   public:
>       void ucitaj(fstream*);
>       const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const;
>
>   private:
>       vector<tuple<string, double>> vrijednosti;
>   };
>
>
>   class TecajnaLista {
>   public:
>       void ucitaj_valutu(string ime_datoteke);
>       const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const;
>
>   private:
>       vector<tuple<string, double>> vrijednosti;
>   };
>
>   /* ########################### moj adapter #################################################*/
>   class Adapter : public TecajnaLista {
>   public:
>       void ucitaj_valutu(string ime_datoteke) {
>           stream.open("tecaj_eur.csv", fstream::in);
>           tecaj.ucitaj(&stream);
>       }
>       const vector<tuple<string, double>>* podaci() const {
>           tecaj.podaci();
>           return &vrijednosti;
>       }
>   protected:
>       vector<tuple<string, double>> vrijednosti;
>       PostojeciProgram::ITecaj* itecaj;
>       PostojeciProgram::Tecaj tecaj;
>       fstream stream;
>   };
>
>   class Statistika {
>   public:
>       static map<string, tuple<double, int>> prosjek(Adapter& adapter);
>   };
>
>   void ispisi(map<string, tuple<double, int>>& pr);
>   void ispisi_tecaj();
>
> }
> ```

**za_adaptaciju.cpp**

> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
>
> #include "za_adaptaciju.h"
>
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
> //=============================================================================
>
> namespace PostojeciProgram {
>   void Tecaj::ucitaj(fstream* datoteka) {
>       string red;
>       while (true) {
>           *datoteka >> red;
>           if (datoteka->eof()) {
>               break;
>           } else {
>               int zarez = red.find(',');
>               string mjesec = red.substr(0, zarez);
>               double cijena = atof(red.substr(zarez + 1, red.size()).c_str());
>               vrijednosti.push_back({mjesec, cijena});
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   const vector<tuple<string, double>>* Tecaj::podaci() const {
>       return &vrijednosti;
>   }
>
>   map<string, tuple<double, int>> Statistika::prosjek(Adapter& tecaj) {
>       map<string, tuple<double, int>> prosjek;
>       for (tuple<string, double> v : *(tecaj.podaci())) {
>           string kljuc = get<0>(v);
>           double nova_vrijednost = get<1>(v);
>
>           tuple<double, int>& p = prosjek[kljuc];
>           double vrijednost = get<0>(p);
>           int broj_pojavljivanja = get<1>(p);
>           if (broj_pojavljivanja == 0) {
>               prosjek[kljuc] = {nova_vrijednost, 1};
>           } else {
>               prosjek[kljuc] = {vrijednost + nova_vrijednost, broj_pojavljivanja + 1};
>           }
>       }
>
>       return prosjek;
>   }
>
>   void ispisi(map<string, tuple<double, int>>& pr) {
>       for (auto v : pr) {
>           string kljuc = get<0>(v);
>           tuple<double, int> v = pr[kljuc];
>           double n = get<0>(v) / get<1>(v);
>           cout << kljuc << ": " << n << endl;
>       }
>   }
>
>   void ispisi_tecaj() {
>       Tecaj p;
>       Adapter adapter;
>
>       adapter.ucitaj_valutu("tecaj_eur.csv");
>
>       map<string, tuple<double, int>> pr = Statistika::prosjek(adapter);
>       ispisi(pr);
>   }
> }
> ```

Program is compiling but I am getting empty result instead of expected result which I am getting with program without adapter :

[Result of program execution without adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4iCY.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is Adapter derived from TecajnaLista if it replaces all of TecajnaLista's functions and data with its own, and never even looks at TecajnaLista's data or functions?  I'm not clear what is being adapted to what. Is it more of a test mock?

Comment: Profesor was very unclear with his request ... I managed to fix program with return tecaj.podaci(); . dunno if that is what he is looking for . Guess i am going to have to find out . Thx for your time !